# Matlab -- how to read file containing file path

Tags: matlab, file, io

I want to read a file containing files paths in Matlab as following:

```
E:\images\0001_127194972.jpg

E:\images\0001_1329737312.jpg

E:\images\0001_1516707027.jpg

.
.
.
```

Comment: what did you try/search?

Comment: What is your difficulty, more specifically? Manipulating the filenames? Opening and reading the file? Or working with jpeg images?

Answer (score 0):

If each lines have only the path in the file, you can do something like following :-

```
fid = fopen('filename.ext');

tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    % Now use tline
    % img = imread (tline) ;
    % do something with img
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```